# Python, how to reshape a "linear" data set format into a matrix-like data set format

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, format

Say I have a data set of the following format

```
                    Date       Value   
AAAA_Property1   2015/07/22     0.01      
AAAA_Property1   2015/07/23     0.02
.
.
.
AAAA_Property2   2015/07/22     0.88
AAAA_Property2   2015/07/23     0.80
.
.
.
.
BBBB_Property1   2015/07/22     0.04      
BBBB_Property1   2015/07/23     0.07
.
.
.
BBBB_Property2   2015/07/22     0.72
BBBB_Property2   2015/07/23     0.70
.
.
.
.
```

As you can see, every AAAA, BBBB, CCCC has a number of properties (property1, property2, etc), spreading overtime. (so it's really a 'cubic' data set)

Now I am wondering how we can group things together, and make the dataset look like the following

```
Name        Date        Property1    Property2   . . . 
AAAA     2015/07/22       0.01          0.3   
AAAA     2015/07/23       0.02          0.4   
.
.
.
BBBB     2015/07/22       0.02          0.4   
BBBB     2015/07/23       0.09          0.7   
.
.
.
```

I need some research on numpy and its ndarray, and know that a reshape() method together with a where() method can probably be used to achieve the goal. But I couldn't put them together, since the data here is really 3-demensional.

However, I did find something else that looks very similar to what I am trying to accomplish. Please take a look at the following data

```
 data = [
        ['Sulfate', 'Nitrate', 'EC', 'OC1', 'OC2', 'OC3', 'OP', 'CO', 'O3'],
        ('Basecase', [
            [0.88, 0.01, 0.03, 0.03, 0.00, 0.06, 0.01, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.07, 0.95, 0.04, 0.05, 0.00, 0.02, 0.01, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.01, 0.02, 0.85, 0.19, 0.05, 0.10, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.02, 0.01, 0.07, 0.01, 0.21, 0.12, 0.98, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.71, 0.74, 0.70, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]]),
        ('With CO', [
            [0.88, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.00, 0.05, 0.00, 0.05, 0.00],
            [0.08, 0.94, 0.04, 0.02, 0.00, 0.01, 0.12, 0.04, 0.00],
            [0.01, 0.01, 0.79, 0.10, 0.00, 0.05, 0.00, 0.31, 0.00],
            [0.00, 0.02, 0.03, 0.38, 0.31, 0.31, 0.00, 0.59, 0.00],
            [0.02, 0.02, 0.11, 0.47, 0.69, 0.58, 0.88, 0.00, 0.00]]),
        ('With O3', [
            [0.89, 0.01, 0.07, 0.00, 0.00, 0.05, 0.00, 0.00, 0.03],
            [0.07, 0.95, 0.05, 0.04, 0.00, 0.02, 0.12, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.01, 0.02, 0.86, 0.27, 0.16, 0.19, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
            [0.01, 0.03, 0.00, 0.32, 0.29, 0.27, 0.00, 0.00, 0.95],
            [0.02, 0.00, 0.03, 0.37, 0.56, 0.47, 0.87, 0.00, 0.00]]),
        ('CO & O3', [
            [0.87, 0.01, 0.08, 0.00, 0.00, 0.04, 0.00, 0.00, 0.01],
            [0.09, 0.95, 0.02, 0.03, 0.00, 0.01, 0.13, 0.06, 0.00],
            [0.01, 0.02, 0.71, 0.24, 0.13, 0.16, 0.00, 0.50, 0.00],
            [0.01, 0.03, 0.00, 0.28, 0.24, 0.23, 0.00, 0.44, 0.88],
            [0.02, 0.00, 0.18, 0.45, 0.64, 0.55, 0.86, 0.00, 0.16]])
    ]
```

I did a help(data), and it turns out to be a list object. But I am struggling on (1) how to get my data into the above format, and (2) how do I extra subset matrices from the above format and perform matrix operations from there.

some mock-up code that I have come up with ...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel('xxx.xlsx', sheetname='1')
myMatrix = df.as_matrix()
myMatrix = myMatrix[:,:].astype(float)
# parse the first column and separate the AAAAs from the Property's
...
for current in ['AAAA','BBBB', ...]:
       mySubMatrix = myMatrix.where(firstColumn == current)
       mySubMatrix = mySubMatrix.reshape(numberOfDates, numberOfProperties)
       #then append mySubMatrix to the new target matrix
```

I don't expect this code to run ... but that is the algorithm I could think of

Comment: Show some code.  What have you already tried?  What do you have so far?

Comment: Pseudo code appended.  Thanks for reminding !

Comment: That's a good addition, and helpful.  But in the future you should try to include some actual working code --- which can be used as the basis for answers / recommendations / improvements.

Comment: OK, I am putting in more effort and will try to get an actual Python code running. Will revert back once I have a Python-version of my pseudo code.